# getChildFragmentManager raise NoSuchMethod exception on 4.0.3 device but not on 4.2.2

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-nested-fragment

I need to use nested fragments for my application and so I'd like to use `getChildFragmentManager`.

I have two devices:

- A real one running on 4.0.3
- A virtual one running on 4.2.2

It works pretty well on the second one but not on my physical device since the call to this method raise a `NoSuchMethod` exception.

```
07-10 19:53:51.722: E/AndroidRuntime(29711): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: fr.epitech.test_esi.fragments.ReservationCalendarFragment.getChildFragmentManager
```

My project use a referenced library so I have downloaded the latest android support library (from SDK manager) and I have added it to both the library and the main project.

[image: Projects view in Eclipse]

Also I decided to set the minimum sdk version supported to 4.0.3 (the version my real device is running on):

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

For both the main project and library.

If anyone has an idea of what I could do wrong, let me know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`getChildFragmentManager()` is only available via the Android Support package's backport of fragments, or on API Level 17+ for native fragments. Hence, if you are trying to use native fragments on API Level 15 or 16, and you are also trying to use `getChildFragmentManager()`, you will get this error.

Comment: Thanks. Having to use Fragment from backport lib is a problem unless there is a way to them with TabListener?

Comment: @nathan: `TabListener` is not tied to any sort of fragment, let alone the native one. You *happen* to be provided a `FragmentTransaction` that you can use, one for native API Level 11 fragments. You do not have to use that `FragmentTransaction`. You are welcome to use your own `FragmentTransaction` from the backport, or do something else that does not involve fragments at all.

Comment: Oh this explains it. I just changed all support fragments to native cause i wouldn't be supporting ICS anymore, and well, seems like I'll still have to use support <_<

Answer (score 0):

try use android.support.v4.app.Fragment instead